# Did the government of Florida reject all K-5 maths books, except for ones issued by a specific ex-employer of a colleague of the current governor?

Tags: politics, education

[This article alleges](https://eu.tallahassee.com/story/news/2022/04/19/desantis-textbooks-florida-woke-one-publisher-allowed-k-5-math-classes/7357965001/) that the only books approved by Governor Ron DeSantis and the Florida Department of Education were published by "Accelerate Learning", a company which happens to have employed fellow Republican Governor Glen Youngkin:

> The Carlyle Group, a global investment firm, acquired Accelerate Learning on Dec. 20, 2018, according to the firm's website.
>
> During that time, Virginia Gov. Glenn Youngkin was the co-CEO of the firm. After 25 years with the company, Youngkin resigned in 2020 to run for office in Virginia.

Is it true that Accelerate Learning is now the only permitted supplier of K-5 Maths textbooks in Florida?

Answer (score 43, accepted):

The headline is slightly misleading, but the story is accurate.

All approved books for *regular* K-5 math are published by Accelerate Learning.  There are 3 approved books for *accelerated* math in 3rd and 4th grade published by other companies.  As the linked article says:

> For regular math classes, Accelerate Learning's STEMscopes Florida Math books are the only option for school districts.
>
> There are two more publisher options for accelerated math, McGraw Hill LLC and Savvas Learning Company LLC, formerly known as Pearson K12 Learning LLC.

This can be seen in the list of approved books from the Florida Department of Education [here](https://www.fldoe.org/core/fileparse.php/5574/urlt/2122MathAdoptedMaterials.pdf).

[image]
[image]

As noted in press releases from the private equity firm The Carlyle Group, Accelerate Learning, Inc. (ALI) was [invested in](https://www.carlyle.com/impact/accelerate-learning) by the Carlyle Group in 2018.

> In 2018, ALI expanded its investor support through a partnership with Carlyle.

Glenn Youngkin worked at The Carlyle Group for 25 years, and [retired](https://www.carlyle.com/media-room/news-release-archive/youngkin-lee-2020-ceo) as Co-CEO in 2020.

> Global investment firm The Carlyle Group (NASDAQ: CG) today announced that Glenn Youngkin has decided to step down as co-CEO of The Carlyle Group and the Board of Directors has appointed Kewsong Lee, who has served as co-CEO with Glenn, as the firm’s chief executive officer.

Comment: Does Carlyle also invest in any other textbook companies? It's quite possible that this tie-in would be true almost no matter which textbooks were

Comment: The story may be approximately accurate, but its implication that there is some kind of cronyism going on is weak.  One should note well that according to the article (1) (only) 40% of around 125 proposed textbooks were rejected, and (2) Florida claims that they were rejected for content reasons (related to sociopolitical topics, not mathematical ones).  That Youngkin's ALI and DeSantis's Florida might have similar views on what sociopolitical themes are appropriate for K-5 textbooks is not a surprise.  That some other publishers might have conflicting ideas wouldn't surprise me, at least.

Comment: @JohnBollinger - I would say that the story's implication that there is some kind of cronyism going on is not just weak, but non-existant.  I see background information on Florida's laws, and on the two companies involved, but no implication of cronyism.

Comment: All the better then, @Mark.  But the present skeptics question, at least, does seem to be focusing -- much more than the referenced article -- on the relationship between DeSantis and Youngkin as context bearing some kind of import.

Comment: In Florida the governor decides what books children can use to learn math?

Comment: @njzk2 Governors only exist to push agendas - the trouble is ever deciding between which agenda to push and whether that agenda is ethical or just comes at the right price

Comment: @JohnBollinger That particular claim (2) would be easier to substantiate if the state would release the disqualifying passages in the rejected texts.

Comment: @njzk2 Yes, by delegation of his agenda, and by promoting and signing laws governing education. Florida Dept of Education ultimately makes the decision. They have to follow the new laws recently promoted and signed by the governor. The Dept of Education is the responsibility of the governor. Its executive and board are appointed by the governor. As no [board members](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Florida_Board_of_Education#Members) have a background in education, draw your own conclusions why they were appointed.

Comment: @corsiKa There is a (possibly paywalled) [New York Times article](https://www.nytimes.com/2022/04/22/us/florida-rejected-textbooks.html) examining passages from the rejected books. It's mostly about "social and emotional learning", developing a "growth mindset", writing down a "math biography" etc.: Help students to become aware of their relationship to math and potentially improve it. Basically apply concepts developed in business and personal counseling. As we know, many students struggle in math, so there is a clear need of and room for improvement. The government didn't like the approach.

Comment: @corsiKa At further reading, there appears to be a perceived connection to the general debate about how to handle systemic racism in schools: Should it be part of the official *material*? Should it inform the *manner* in which schools teach? The Florida government, strongly against teaching or otherwise considering racism in schools, seems to draw a connection here: Like with health, jobs, housing, insurance and a myriad other things race may have an impact on school success, including in math. This may surface upon reflection, against government policies. Hence the rejections.